# Why not run uwsgi instances as root

Tags: python, nginx, docker, uwsgi

I am reading through the uWSGI documentation and it warns to *[always avoid running your uWSGI instances as root](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#security-and-availability)*. What is the reason behind this?

Does it matter if it is the only process (besides nginx) running in a docker container, serving up a flask application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, security reasoning says that running as root as bad. If there were any kind of bug, for example a code execution bug that can allow anybody to execute arbitrary code they would be able to destroy your entire system.

If you don't run the process as root, any code execution vulnerabilities would need to be paired with a secondary privilege escalation vulnerability in order to destroy your system.

In a docker container, this is mitigated slightly in that you'll be able to recover your old system relatively easily, however, it is generally still a bad practice or habit to allow processes to run as root as a malicious attacker can and will steal the information that may exist on your server or turn your server into a malware delivery mechanism.